# Finding SD-Card Path in Android 4.4 Kitkat

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

In one of my application i'm accessing some files in the sd card. I'm using the below function to determine the mounted sd-card path.

```
File file = new File("/system/etc/vold.fstab");
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String path = "";

    try {
        fr = new FileReader(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    try {
        if (fr != null) {
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String s = br.readLine();
            while (s != null) {
                if (s.startsWith("dev_mount")) {
                    String[] tokens = s.split("\\s");

                    path = tokens[2]; //mount_point
                }
                s = br.readLine();
            }
        }            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fr != null) {
                fr.close();
            }            
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return path;
```

This works for all the devices prior to Kitkat. But in Kitkat version i'm getting **FileNotFoundException** on line 1,

```
File file = new File("/system/etc/vold.fstab");
```

I found so many articles about updated sd card permission in Android kitkat version.But still a bit confused about that... 
Please can anyone help me to sort it out??? Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you want an actual (removable) SD card, then on 4.4+ you need to use the new standard APIs for that.  If you want the External Storage, its existing API continues to work.

Comment: I checked the latest android kitkat doc's about external storage and they are just explained about the getExternalFilesDirs() method. Can you give me any lead to the new api's??

Answer (score 0):

vold.fstab is no longer used in 4.3. Instead, fstab. is now present.

Refer to http://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/ although it is not very clear

Answer (score -1):

You must call to :

```
File sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

to know the path of SD card. This function call invoke system operative function wich determine the path of SD card. And to know the state of external storage you must use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState()
```

function.

Comment: If they want the External Storage and not an SD card, yes.  But I suspect that is not the question actually asked.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the Android docs say, "Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer."

Comment: @MattPassell - phones running Android 4.4 are probably going to be using permanently installed memory as their "External Storage" with any SD card slot treated as auxiliary storage - the likely exception where you might still see the "old method" of a removable SD to implement it would be development boards and embedded devices running Android.  There's never been a reason to poll vold for the "External Storage" rather than use it's API, so the poster's starting with that strongly suggests they want an auxiliary storage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - OK. Things have definitely gotten more complicated since the last time I experimented with writing Android apps.

Comment: Actually i want the mounted storage path (sd-card). This gives me the external storage path and this doesn't assure it is sd-card.